# Problem with Appendix sub-indices

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

Is it possible to index the sub sections of an Appendix, both in the table of contents and the Appendix itself? At the moment, what I am getting is something like the picture attached; The subsections are indexed in both locations, yet the the capital letter (e.g. A) is missing and the numbering starts with a dot (.). Any ideas?

[image]

EDIT1: The same issue appears in the "List of Figures" and "List of Tables" as well. In that case, apart from capital A, dot is also omitted.

EDIT2: Here is the [project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5301947/CUEDThesisPSnPDF.zip).

Comment: Please edit your question to provide examples of the code you're using at present or, better yet, a full MWE (minimum working example) that generates the issues you're trying to resolve. There are a lot of components involved in the creation of tables of contents, lists of figures and tables, and section headers as well; without knowledge of your specific setup, it's going to be difficult for anyone to provide a satisfactory solution.

Comment: @Mico It is part of a big project and unfortunately I am newbie at LaTeX. Could I post the link of the template I am using?

Comment: You certainly can. Just be sure to include as much of the relevant LaTeX code as you can. Thanks.

Comment: @Mico Thank you! Just uploaded the project.

Comment: Instead of uploading your complete project please read: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It is not the complete project. It is actually the template, thus a minimum working example.

Comment: do _not_ use the command `\backmatter` and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a closer look at your project file. In my opinion your document class isn't a good choise.

Nevertheless your document class based on the standard document class `book`.

If you use the command `\backmatter` the internal conditional `\if@mainmatter` is set to `false`. This means that that `\chapter` doesn't get any number nor prefix.

To show this behavior here a little example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\backmatter
\chapter{bar}
\end{document}
```

Based on this information the level section with the prefix number `\thechapter` can be printed because you are using `\backmatter`.

---

At this point I want to recommend one of the modern document class `memoir` or `scrbook`. Both are well documented. I also recommend that you should avoid such templates. You will never know what the document class do.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I start using this template mainly because it was the best one I managed to found out there. I have almost finished my study, and now I just formatting the report. I don't think that I have the time to learn LaTeX from the beginning at this point, However, I very much appreciate your suggestions. But, could you please tell me again what should I do in order to fix that problem?

Comment: @eualin: In this case for the future ;-) -- Nevertheless comment `\backmatter` .

Comment: Apologise for the previous message. I wasn't quick enough to edit it before time-out expires. I tried to place \backmatter in the main file and the compile the project, but unfortunately it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `\backmatter` is set in your main file. You have to remove it.

Comment: Good catch that the command `\backmatter` disables numbering of chapters!